# Passing input values into an action from a javascript created input elements

Tags: javascript, html, grails

Is it possible to add to the web page params object dynamically via a js once the web page is displayed and from input values from elements created dynamically within a js?

If so it would enable me to transfer web data into a single action.

Here is some of the js code where new elements are created dynamically via user input on a single page.

```
        // Create a new caption cell.....
        newCapCell = document.createElement("TD");
        newCapCell.setAttribute("id", "cap_"+iF);
        newCapNode = document.createElement("INPUT");
        newCapNode.setAttribute("id", "cap_"+iF);
        newCapNode.setAttribute("type", "text");
        newCapNode.setAttribute("value", "Input Caption Data");
        capList.push("Input Caption Data")
        //newCapNode = document.createTextNode("Caption");
        newCapCell.appendChild(newCapNode);
        newRow.appendChild(newCapCell);
```

Here is the form configuration that directs the flow to the multiFileSave action to which I want to add these new elements values.

```
    <g:uploadForm action="multiFileSave" name="mikeK" params="[videoTemplateId=videoTemplateId]">
        <fieldset class="buttons">
                <span class="pageHeader"><g:message code="Upload a New Picture" /></span>
        <g:submitButton name="Create Video" id="FileButton" onclick="fileUpload.selectButton()" class="buttons" value="${message(code: 'default.button.save.label', default: 'Create Video')}" />
        </fieldset>
```

What happens at the moment works intermittently - both the action "multiFileSave" and the js script "fileUpload.selectButton()" are invoked simulteniously.

The "multiFileSave" action relies on the "fileUpload.selectButton()" and its linked action to be completed which is not always the case due to the asynchronous nature of this.

So if I can pass the element values into params for the web page then all the data can go through the single "multiFileSave" action only where I can force sequential action.

-mike